# C# get index of bit

Tags: c#

I want to get the index of the first bit that equal to 1, and the index of the last bit that equal to 1.
For example:

data=0x3E

first bit = 1

last bit = 5

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you know anything about binary? Have you made any attempts?

Comment: [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are some fun bit-twiddling tricks you can use, but here's a naive solution:

```
public static void Main()
{
    uint data = 0x3E;
    uint firstMask = 1;
    uint lastMask = 0x80000000;
    int? first = null;
    int? last = null;

    for (int i=0; i < 32; i++) {
        if ((firstMask & data) > 0 && first == null)
        {
            first = i;
        }
        if ((lastMask & data) != 0 && last == null)
        {
            last = i;
        }
        firstMask = firstMask << 1;
        lastMask = lastMask >> 1;
    }
    last = 31-last;


    Console.WriteLine(first);
    Console.WriteLine(last);
}
```

See http://dotnetfiddle.net/FmN7QL

Comment: Don't know who is down voting all answers without giving any reason at all. Things like this pisses me off...even more when we're just trying to help.

Comment: What? did I do something bad?

Comment: I know, right. I got downvoted twice, and my answer was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and its [Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.item%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. Then you could create a BitArray and loop it's items to get what you want easily.

Answer (score -1):

Manually build a lookup table:

```
var firstBit = new int[0x100] { -1, 0, 1, 0 ... };
var lastBit  = new int[0x100] { -1, 0, 1, 1 ... };
```

Then use 'data' to index into those tables.

```
byte data = 0x3e;    
var f = firstBit[data];
var l = lastBit[data];
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to automate the creation of the tables. :)

Comment: What is these tables.? And how they are spending the right answer?

Comment: Spending the right answer? I don't understand what that means. It appears that you already know how to do figure it out, since you provided the solution for 0x3e. If you just provide the solution for all input values in a lookup table, then you've solved the problem.

Comment: I did not understand how did you build the above tables